# How to pass DbSet as generic parameter?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, .net-core, fluentvalidation

I have a custom validator for FluentValidation to validate whether `Guid` exist in the Database.

```
public static class TestCustomValidator
{
    public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, Guid> MustExistInDatabase<T>(this IRuleBuilder<T, Guid> ruleBuilder, ApplicationContext context)

    return ruleBuilder.Must(id => context.Product.Find(id) != null).WithMessage("'{PropertyName}' {PropertyValue} not found.");
}
```

Then I will call it like this

```
RuleFor(r => r.ProductId).NotEmpty().MustExistInDatabase(context);
```

However, this part `context.Product.Find(id) != null` is currently only for `Product` and I have a lot of tables so I was hoping I could do something like

```
RuleFor(r => r.ProductId).NotEmpty().MustExistInDatabase<Product>();  
RuleFor(r => r.CustomerId).NotEmpty().MustExistInDatabase<Customer>();
```

And it would automatically look for the `Product` or `Customer` table. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: This will help you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext.set?view=entity-framework-6.2.0

Answer (score 1):

You can define a base class as follows and inherit entities from it

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class Product : BaseEntity
{
    //other properties
}

public class Customer : BaseEntity
{
    //other properties
}
```

Then change your extension method as below

```
public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, Guid> MustExistInDatabase<T>(this IRuleBuilder<T, Guid> ruleBuilder, ApplicationContext context) where T : BaseEntity
{
   return ruleBuilder.Must(id => context.Set<T>().Find(id) != null).WithMessage("'{PropertyName}' {PropertyValue} not found.");
}
```

and use as follows :

```
RuleFor(r => r.ProductId).NotEmpty().MustExistInDatabase<Product>(dbContext);  
RuleFor(r => r.CustomerId).NotEmpty().MustExistInDatabase<Customer>(dbContext);
```